# Java data access for programming interviews

Tags: java, database

I'm studying for a programming interview in Java which may involve database access.  Is there a good, easy framework that I can learn quickly and use during the programming test part of my interview?  JDBC?

Comment: I would strongly advise *against* this sort of thing. If you haven't done any database work, say so in the interview.

Comment: I will say so before the interview but will be prepared in the event that I have no choice in what kind of interview test I am given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with DB concepts and wish to play around with Java, JDBC is a good place to start. It has a clean and neat API which will enable you to perform various database operations as you wish.

If you are looking for something more advanced, like Object-Relational-Mappings, then JPA (Java Persistence API) is a widely accepted standard. This is just a specification, so for concrete implementations you should refer to Hibernate, OpenJPA or TopLink.

I would assume that if they want to ask you about database access in Java then they are referring to JDBC, since JPA is a wider concept. From my experience, if interviewers want to see if I have experience in JPA, they usually say that in the job post.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is absolutely nothing done with databases in Java that does not involve JDBC.

However, nowadays it's relatively uncommon to work with JDBC directly; most framework provide some sort of abstraction, often in the form of an object-relational mapper (ORM) like JPA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLExecutor (http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365233/SQLExecutor-A-Simple-Open-Source-JDBC-Framework)

It reduces code a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can study Hibernate framework.This is easy to learn and very useful for data access in Java Development and is used mostly.For Basics of this,you can refer to www.roseindia.net and for practical examples,you can refer to www.vannilla.com.